# Trying to replace text between '*' using fetch request

Tags: regex, post, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api

I am building a Chrome Extension that does *Speech-to-Text* into Google Documents. The API I am using sends me 2 types of data registered by speech, some that come faster but are less accurate and the others vice-versa. Right now, I am first writing the faster ones to Docs, then I want it replaced with the more accurate version. First I've tried to save the faster version into a buffer so that I can replace it easily after:

```
const requests = [
                    {
                        replaceAllText: {
                            replaceText: recivedMyText + ' ',
                            containsText: {
                                text: buffMyText,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ];
```

But there is sometimes a problem that **buffMyText** doesn't save exactly the same text that is sent to the document (it may have random junk that basically cancels the replacement for that part).
So I've tried an alternative where I add an * to the faster text, so I can replace everything between asterisks in the Document. I've tried this using replacement with regex:

```
const requests = [
                    {
                        replaceAllText: {
                            replaceText: recivedMyText + '',
                            containsText: {
                                matchCase: true,
                                text: regex,
                                wildcardRegex: true, 
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ];
```

With the following regex variable: `const regex = '\\*(.*?)\\*';`  
This was the first time I used regex, so the expression can be wrong but from what I've tried on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/2tr28) I understand it does what I want.

Here is the updated request with the version from @sln

```
const requests = [
                    {
                        replaceAllText: {
                            replaceText: recivedMyText,
                            containsText: {
                                matchCase: true, 
                                text: '([\S\s]*?)(?=\*)', // prettier-ignore
                                wildcardRegex: true, 
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ];
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `+ ''`?

Comment: What is this object? Is it a parameter to a library? Can you add a link to the documentation?

Comment: `\*(.*?)\*` just matches from one asterisk to the next that is on the same line. To span lines, replace it with this : `\*([\S\s]*?)\*` And if you do not want the asterisks, use lookarounds `(?<=\*)([\S\s]*?)(?=\*)`. Modern JS supports lookhehinds.

Comment: the + '' was used to add a space between words on document. I've updated with the new regex **const regex = "([\S\s]*?)(?=\\*)"; // prettier-ignore**, but it still dosen't seem to be working.

Comment: Your update missed lookaround from sln's advice. Should be `regex = "(?<=\*)([\S\s]*?)(?=\*)";`